# Which MySQL storage engine should I use?

Tags: mysql

I don't think innoDB could work because I need to truncate often very large tables (some GB) and i need every bit of disk space.

I have 3 tables that contain over 2 millions rows. I need to do a large number of queries for second (>50). I have only one user.

Comment: Use InnoDB so you can use a RDMBS like an RDMBS. MyISAM is a joke for actual RDMBS properties.

Comment: Voters to migrate: Please do not vote to migrate this anywhere. This question needs way more detail to be answerable. It is not good form to migrate questions that need improvement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InnoDB` tables area transactional and only useful where you may need to revert a commit in case something goes wrong specifically in a RDMBS environment. Based on the information you have provided which is not to none, if your only requirement is fast reads and writes I would say go with `MyISAM`. There are other engines too which are in-memory (definitely not a good idea with GB's of data) and have various other properties, but without more details it's hard to say if one of the others is a better fit.

Comment: Thanks. What other informations would be useful?

Comment: Have a read into [what each storage engine is meant for](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html) and see what suits your fancy. Other considerations could include, amount and deletes and updates, types and size of indexes, is full text search required etc. Look at [`ARCHIVE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html) if retrieval and indexing is not important, it minimizes data footprint and is meant to store large amounts of data.